# Could not find wsdlLocation in additional metadatafiles

Tags: jboss, wsdl, jax-ws

I have jax-ws web service (jboss implementation) configured with annotation.

@WebService([...], wsdlLocation = "/WEB-INF/wsdl/service.wsdl")

The wsld file is included into war file. The war file is included into ear file, that is deployed on JBoss (version: 5.0.1.GA).

During deployment I receive error message like that:
"Could not find /WEB-INF/wsdl/service.wsdl in the additional metadatafiles!"

I tried to put the file in many places:
- META-INF folder of war file,
- META-INF folder of ear file,
- classpath of war file,

but I it didn't help.

Anyone knows how should I configure it?

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and i solved like this:

`@WebService(targetNamespace="http://my.app.it/", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/additional.wsdl")`

(WEB-INF not start with slash)

Answer (score 0):

To address this issue, I placed the WSDLs into the jar file that I had created from the generated stubs.  Then set the wsdllocation and all was good.

example of my ant target:

```
<target name="genclients" depends="clean, -createdirs">
    <wsimport
        fork="true"
        xnocompile="true"
        wsdl="${src.resource.dir}\${wsdl.name}"
        wsdllocation="/resources/${wsdl.name}"
        sourcedestdir="${src.generated.dir}"
        verbose="true"
        destdir="${target.classes.dir}"
        keep="true"
        extension="true"
        debug="true"
        package="com.fedex.ship.stub"
        xadditionalHeaders="true"
        binding="${basedir}/binding.xml"
        >
        <arg line="-mark-generated"/>
    </wsimport>

    <javac srcdir="${src.generated.dir}" destdir="${target.classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="1.6" target="1.6" debug="true" deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </javac>

    <copy todir="${target.classes.dir}" preservelastmodified="true" overwrite="true">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}" >
        <include name="**/*.wsdl"/>
        <include name="**/*.xsd"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>

    <pathconvert property="manifest.classpath" pathsep=" ">
        <mapper>
            <chainedmapper>
                <flattenmapper />
            </chainedmapper>
        </mapper>
        <path>
        </path>
    </pathconvert>

    <mkdir dir="${target.classes.dir}/META-INF"/>
    <manifest file="${target.classes.dir}/META-INF/manifest.mf">
        <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${manifest.classpath}"/>
    </manifest>

    <jar jarfile="${target.jar.dir}/${jar.name}" basedir="${target.classes.dir}" manifest="${target.classes.dir}/META-INF/manifest.mf" excludes=".settings,**/.svn"/>

    <!--
    <delete failonerror="false" includeEmptyDirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${target.classes.dir}"/>
    </delete>
    -->

</target>
```